# Цифровая клавиатура

Tags: android, клавиатура, android-softkeyboard

Как я могу создать такую же клавиатуру как на скриншоте ниже?

***Примечание***: это не отдельные кнопки, являющиеся частью activity, а именно soft keyboard, потому что при переключении soft keyboard со swiftkey на aosp и обратно эти кнопки тоже меняется.

Отсюда я могу сделать вывод, что реализовать такое всё же возможно. Но как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: android-studio никак не связана с вашим вопросом, просьба использовать данную метку только в вопросах о IDE

Comment: https://customkeyboarddetails.blogspot.com/2019/02/available-resources-for-android.html

Comment: @Andrew, прошу прощения, больше не буду.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja о, это то, что я искал, но не смог нагуглить. Спасибо

Comment: @NikMAX, все ок) могли не знать :) просто на будущее :D

Comment: Нужно свою клавиатуру делать